Is it safe to override the HTMLAnchorElement href property with a setter?
I want to add a referrer to all anchors on my site. I have this POC that works.
const originalHrefDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'href');

Object.defineProperty(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'href', {
  set(val) {
    originalHrefDescriptor.set.call(this, `${val}?referrer=https://example.com`);
  }
});

This solution is great because it works for every anchor, regardless of the frontend framework that the site is using, so it can be used almost anywhere.
My question is: Is there a really strong reason for me not to use this approach?
The alternative approach is to bind click handlers everywhere, but the surface area to achieve that is much greater.

I'd rather recommend doing that in a delegate click event handler, not by overwriting the .href setter. I'd be worried about this breaking some abused a elements (e.g. for URL polyfills) or failing to handle .setAttribute('href', …)

Yes @Bergi, that would absolutely be best practice, but I'm exploring using this option for a very specific reason: which is guaranteeing coverage on a large number of legacy sites, where going in and adding click handlers to each anchor is a mountain of a task.
However you make an excellent point, which is that I'll need to ensure I explore all other avenues code might be using to set the href.

"adding click handlers to each anchor" - not to each anchor. Use event delegation and attach only a single handler to the document node, then check on each click whether an anchor with a href was the target.

@Bergi you're a genius, thank you that's way more elegant! I didn't recognise that's what you meant immediately. Do you want to post that as an answer for me to mark as correct? If not I'll just add this solution myself.
